# Hide primefaces overlaypanel from managed bean failed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces overlay panel in my form and intention is to control the overlay panel visibility from managed bean, so i have set widgetVar to overlay and when try to hide the overlay panel from managed bean its throwing error

```
<p:overlayPanel id="imagePanel" for="input_ac" widgetVar="overlaypanel" showEvent="keypress"  hideEffect="fade"  >                 
   <p:outputLabel value="test"  />
</p:overlayPanel>
```

ManagedBean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("overlaypanel.hide()");
```

ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved, updated code
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('overlaypanel').hide();");`